# How to get the digits after the decimal point

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I have `N[Sqrt[2], 8]` which outputs `0.4142136`

How do I get the `4142136` part out of it?
I tried `RealDigits[N[Sqrt[2], 8] - Floor@Sqrt[2]][[1]]` but because in the solution above the last digit was rounded up (`0.41421356`), it doesn't come out the same : `{4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5}`

Comment: I would be helpful if you could add what you want to do with the result. Do you need an integer like `4142136` or a string `"4142136"` or is a list like your last output OK?

Comment: halirutan, I want a list of digits or a number. In the end I need to add the digits after the decimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
FractionalPart@N[Sqrt[2], 7] 10^7 // Round
(* 4142136*)
```

Comment: That works, thanks :] I thought about doing it that way but for some reason decided that it wouldn't work for a large number of sig figs >.> ... but it totally does ... <.<

Answer (score 4):

A way to work with `RealDigits`, if desired:

```
Drop @@ RealDigits[Round[Sqrt[2], 1*^-7]] // FromDigits
```

> ```
> 4142136
> ```